# Adding job parameter in before job doesnt work spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job wherein I need to set job parameter in beforeStep
I am using below code for the same:

```
@Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        String pid = fetchPid();
        jobExecution
            .getJobParameters()
            .getParameters()
            .put("pid", new JobParameter(pid));
    }
```

When I run above code and debug , I see that `pid` is not present in the jobparameters . What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

> What could be wrong here?

The `JobParameters#getParameters` returns a unmodifiable map of parameters (See [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParameters.html#getParameters--)). So adding the `pid` key as you did it wont work.

> I need to set job parameter in beforeStep

I guess you mean in `beforeJob` and not `beforeStep` since your code shows the `beforeJob` method. Using the `JobExecutionListener` to add parameters is too late because the parameters are used to identify the instance, and at the time of invoking `beforeJob`, the execution has been already launched with the given parameters. You need to prepare the parameters *upfront* then use them to launch the job using `jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters)`.